# How to parse HTML table to JSON in one JSONObject?

Tags: php, html, json, html-table

I want parse html table to json with this code :

```
  foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
        $name = $row->find('td',0)->innertext;
        $status = $row->find('td',1)->innertext;
        $json['item'][$i]['name'] = strip_tags($name);
        $json['item'][$i++]['status'] = strip_tags($status);
    }
   echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

my output is :

```
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "وضعیت بازار",
      "status": "باز "
    },
    {
      "name": "شاخص کل",
      "status": "1,955,717.18 2806.33"
    },
    {
      "name": "شاخص كل (هم وزن)",
      "status": "510,466.24 720.27"
    }
  ]
}
```

but i want outout like this :

```
[
  "item":{
  
    "name1": "شاخص کل",
    "status1": "1,952,910.02 "
    "name2": "شاخص كل (هم وزن)",
    "status2": "509,746 "
    "name3": "ارزش بازار",
    "status3": "73,021,094.824 B"
    
   ...etc
  }
]
```

anybody can help me ?
Any ideas? what can i to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the counter to the key of the object

```
$json['item']['name' + $i] = strip_tags($name);
$json['item']['status' + $i] = strip_tags($status);
$i++
```